# datagridview.Rows[i] very slow?

Tags: c#, winforms

The `dgv.Rows[i]` is very slow in the following code.

```
var firstVisible = dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
var visibleCount = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(true);
for (var i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++) // 20K+ rows, maybe 100K rows
{
    var row = dgv.Rows[i];
    if (i < firstVisible || i > firstVisible + visibleCount) { AddKeyCellValuesToHashSet(row); }
    else { AddKeyCellValueAndDGVRowToDictionary(row); } // visible rows
```

The CPU Usage of the Diagnostic Tools shows the called function is

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_item(Int32)$#...1669
```

I need to loop all the rows to get the list of a couple of column cells of the rows which are not displayed in the grid view. Is there a faster way to do it? Can I just loop the data source of the data grid view? Not sure if it still works after the grid view is sorted by some columns.

Comment: Is `row` needed outside the `if`-block? You could reduce the number of calls to `Rows[i]` by moving it inside the `if`. Not sure if it will get much faster though. Do you have a large number of rows?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Rows[i]` call? The "displayed" methods are a much more likely suspect.

Comment: Also, I think the `firstVisible` and `visibleCount` could be defined before your `for`-loop, because they probably don't change during the loop?

Comment: @HHLV, yes, I will need the visible rows too. The two definitions are out of the loop. I copied two to the wrong place when creating the question. Updated.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, the tool shows the `dgv.Rows[i]` uses 3 to 4 seconds.

Comment: You should not show 20K row in a `DataGridView`. Load and show data page by page. For example 10 or 100 rows per page.

Comment: The source code of the indexer can be seen here if it helps in any way: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/DataGridViewRowCollection.cs.html#2187b5f83bac983b

Comment: This looks like a DGV row un-sharing issue.  Learn about [Using Shared Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control#using-shared-rows) and using the [DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.sharedrow?view=netframework-4.7.2).  If you need to access the row's values, it is preferable to access the underlying bound source (a DataView if using DataTable as the source).

Comment: @TnTinMn, will the index of the bound source align with the `DataGridView.Rows` (or shared rows) after the data grid view was sorted by some columns? (I'm using some extended data grid view which can be sorted by double-clicking the column headers)

Comment: For the case of a DGV bound to either a DataView or directly to a DataTable (the DGV binds to the DataTable.DefaultView), the DGV's row indices directly correlate to the DataView.Item indices. If sorting is performed by setting the DataView.Sort property this direct correlation is maintained. For your extended DGV, I would suggest that you use the debugger to observe the DataView.Sort property to see if is changing while you change sort columns. If the property matches the selected sort, then you are good to go and access the DataView by index.